# How to draw a transparent circle in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

To be clear, I don't want a transparent disk, but a circle drawn with a transparent marker. Is there a simple way to do it? None of the circle drawing primitives (rectangle and viscircles) seem to support ahlpa properties. I have considered using a scatter plot, but the sizes of those circles are set in points squared, which I am not sure I am willing to deal with (as opposed to simply setting the radius of the circle).

Comment: Are you sure that `rectangle` doesn’t have an EdgeAlpha property? Not all properties show in the inspector or the docs. Try to set it, see if it works.

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't work: `Error using rectangle
There is no EdgeAlpha property on the Rectangle class.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most colors in Matlab support a fourth input value which is transparency with values between 0 and 1 where:

- **0:** fully transparent
- **1:** fully opaque (default)

Here's some example code with opaque red circle with semi-transparent green circle on top.

```
h1 = rectangle('Position',[1 2 5 6],'Curvature',[1,1]); %1,1, gives circle
h1.FaceColor = 'r';

h2 = rectangle('Position',[2 3 6 7],'Curvature',[1,1]);
h2.FaceColor = [0 1 0 0.2]; %mostly transparent green [R G B alpha]
```

[image]